# How to do a page curl flipping in xamarin forms

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms

I need to implement a page flip animation in my xamarin forms app.I tried with flipping but that doesn't give a perfect look.

I want a page flip like  below link.
https://youtu.be/s-Q12A-Pej4

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, here is a helpful discussion .https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23918/ui-how-to-flip-a-card-with-animation

Comment: I already tried with the last one in the above discussion. But I didn't get a perfect look

Comment: Okey , if get more good solution will share here .

Answer (score 1):

you can write below code in xaml.cs for Page Flip Animation .
    `this.TranslateTo(100, 0, 400); 

     await this.RotateYTo(-90, 200); 

     this.RotationY = -270; 

     this.RotateYTo(-360, 200); 

     await this.TranslateTo(0, 0, 220); 

     this.RotationY = 0;`

this is basic logic for FlipAnimation you can modified if needed

Comment: I already tried with this code , I want a page flipping animation like the above link. Thanks for your response.